# Java warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I have the following (partial) class:

```
public class Graph<O> {
    private ArrayList<Edge> edges;

    public ArrayList<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }
}
```

Now, when calling the method `getEdges()` somewhere else and storing the result in a variable of type `ArrayList<Edge>`, I get `warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion`:

```
OtherFile.java:101: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        ArrayList<Edge> edges = graph.getEdges();
                                              ^
  required: ArrayList<Edge>
  found:    ArrayList
```

I have looked at multiple other questions about this warning, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. `getEdges()` returns `ArrayList<Edge>`, so why can't I store its result in a variable of that exact type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That warning would come when you invoke the `getEdges()` method on raw type `Graph`. When that is the case, all the generic types are replaced with their erasure. So, for `Graph` raw type, the method signature becomes like:

```
public ArrayList getEdges();
```

Solution is to use parameterized type or wildcard types.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the definition of `graph` in the other file (class) from `Graph` to `Graph<?>` and now it compiles without errors indeed :)