# List<T> returns an object collection

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I was working on a part of an in-house library today and wanted to improve some things by adding basic generics to our "Game" class.

Here is the stripped down version of the, now changed, game class:

```
public abstract class Game<G extends GamePlayer> {
    private final List<G> players;

    public Game() {
        this.players = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public Collection<G> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
}
```

Pretty standard, I know. But when I wanted to use the getPlayers() method in a game module like this: `for (GamePlayer player : game.getPlayers())` All it gave me was an error that the return type equals "`Collection<Object>`" instead of "`Collection<G>`".

All other functions I have (like `G getPlayer(String name)`) return the correct type, but not the getPlayers function.

I really want to avoid implementations of this library cast their players to things like
`MyGamePlayer player = (MyGamePlayer) myGame.getPlayer("dummy")`.

What did I do wrong with the generics?

**Edit:**

Here is the class that contains the `for` loop:

```
   public class GiftTask implements Runnable {
        private final Game game;
        private final Item[] items;


        public GiftTask(Game game, List<Item> itemList) {
            this.game = game;

            this.items = itemList.toArray(new Item[itemList.size()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (GamePlayer player : game.getPlayers()) { // This line has the error
                player.getInventory().addItem(items);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Everything looks good to me here. Can you show us the code that produces the error?

Comment: How you create instance of Game(myGame ref)?

Comment: @SergeyMorozov Well, the get methods work fine. I get the correct type of instance. I only have that issue with the collection…

Comment: Are you using raw type `Game`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java warning: \[unchecked\] unchecked conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744197/java-warning-unchecked-unchecked-conversion)

Comment: Updated my original post RohitJain, Keppil

Comment: `getPlayers` -> `getPlayers()`, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use this:

```
private final Game<GamePlayer> game;
```

you're using the raw type of `Game`.

Comment: Well, This is part of my library (even the "gift" module that runs on a timer) - so I dont have a game implementation. I always thought that generics at least return their base type, in this case GamePlayer. It is working for the ``getPlayer()`` part just fine!

Comment: @SpaceEmotion Then, just use `Game<GamePlayer>`.

Comment: @SpaceEmotion I don't see how your `getPlayer()` works. Did you go through the duplicate question that I linked in your question? You shouldn't be using raw types, else you're bound to get such issues.

Comment: But what if an implementation like ``MyGame<MyGamePlayer>`` wants to use that "gift" module - would that still work with the generics? (``MyGamePlayer`` obviously extends ``GamePlayer``)

Comment: @RohitJain I'm acutally using a ``Map<String, G> players`` in the original code. the players.values() just returns a ``Collection<G>``. I also tested it with a list-only implementation, same problem.

Comment: How do you want to use "gift" module, which we don't even know what it is, in `MyGame<MyGamePlayer>`? Mostly you should be able to use it, if you've designed your classes properly. And can you show some more code showing how `getPlayer()` is working?

Comment: @RohitJain `G getPlayer()` where `G extends GamePlayer` erases to `GamePlayer getPlayer()` so it works for him mostly by chance. Not so with `Collection<G> getPlayers()`, which erases to `Collection getPlayers()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oops! Was missing the bounds :)

Comment: Okay, I just made a bigger pastebin with the two important classes (removed the unimportant stuff): http://pastebin.com/HGZmBbZS. @MarkoTopolnik was right with his statement; ``getPlayer()`` erases to ``GamePlayer`` return type when I only use the raw object. Would that mean, that if I'd be using an array of GamePlayers instead, this would work perfectly fine?