# Odd java type behavior

Tags: java

I'm seeing some behavior I don't understand in the generic type of Map.entrySet. If I iterate through a typed map, I get expected types, e.g.

```
HashMap<A,B> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<A,B> e: map.entrySet(){ ... }
```

However, if I have an untyped map, the iterated type of the entry set is being reported as Object:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
a) for (Map.Entry e: map.entrySet(){ ... } // this will fail, e is being reported as "Object"
b) for (Object o: map.entrySet(){ ... } // this is compilable.
```

Shouldn't I be able to get an untyped entry as in statement a)? If I look at the hashmap implementation in the jvm, I see this:

```
c) public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() { ...
```

This behavior seems to imply that because the K,V is not specified in the second example, somehow the entire typing of the set contents in c) is omitted. Can anyone shed any light on this? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22744197/1679863)

Comment: If one thing is raw, everything else becomes raw; it's not just treated as if it were `Object`.  (And that's why you never use rawtypes in new code.)

Answer (score 3):

The `entrySet` method returns `Set<K, V>`.  However, when you use a raw type for your `HashMap`, all generics in the type undergo type erasure, and the `entrySet` method just returns a `Set`.  Iterating over a raw `Set` will yield `Object`s.

Comment: I get that, but what seemed counterintuitive is that the erasure gives you Object instead of an untyped Map.Entry since the untyped map has enough information to determine that it's returning (untyped) Map.Entry values.